# Hibernate OneToMany with OrderBy generates invalid SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a one-to-many relationship as follows:

```
public class Player {
    private int           id;
    private String        name;
    private List<Payment> payments;

    ... accessors etc
}

public class Payment {
    private int        id;
    private Date       when;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    ... accessors etc
}
```

orm to describe these:

```
<entity-mappings ... version="2.0">

    <entity class="domain.Player" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>

            <basic name="name" optional="false" />

            <one-to-many name="payments" fetch="EAGER">
                <order-by>when</order-by>
                <cascade><cascade-all/></cascade>
            </one-to-many>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

    <entity class="domain.Payment" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>

            <basic name="when"   optional="false" />
            <basic name="amount" optional="false" />
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

This works fine with Hibernate 4.2.2.Final, but if I update to 4.3.4.Final it fails whenever I try to load objects of type player.  The SQL generated by 4.3.4.Final is along the lines of :

```
select ... 
from Player player0_ 
left outer join Player_Payment payments1_ on player0_.id=payments1_.Player_id 
left outer join Payment payment2_ on payments1_.payments_id=payment2_.id 
where player0_.id=? 
order by payments1_.when
```

i.e. the ORDER BY is on the join table, not the target table.

Any ideas - am I doing something wrong here or does this look like a Hibernate bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping is correct. This Hibernate bug reported in [HHH-8834](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8834). Attached test case in bug report uses annotations, but otherwise it matches to the one in question.

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried searching Hibernate's JIRA but hadn't been able to find this.  This is exactly the same problem, so thanks for the link.